# How to send clock message from arduino to MIDI synth?

Tags: arduino, clock, midi, tempo

I'm trying to send periodically clock from arduino to Electron Digitakt synth with `120 bpm`. It means I need to send `0xF8` every 21ms (`60000/bpm/ppq -> ppq = 24 pulses per quarter`)

My code looks like

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(31250);

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { Serial.write(byte(0xFF)); } // reset the slave
  
  Serial.write(byte(0xFA)); // send start command
  delay(10);

}

void loop () {
    Serial.write(byte(0xF8));
    delay(21);
}
```

But I see that my synth switches to Play but `BPM` doesn't change. I use logic analyser to check the output, it shows that this byte sends every 21ms (+- 1.2ms, usually a half of ms). Tried several libs for arduino with midi management, nothing helped

Could you help me to understand where is an issue?

Comment: I was hoping someone else would reply so I also could find out what's wrong. It sure looks OK to me. Maybe put a delay right after the `Serial.begin`?  I  see that sometimes with other Serial connections.  Maybe see what Midi Ox or MIDI Monitor show you?  Double check the hardware connections, I guess.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [MIDI tutorial for programmers](http://www.music-software-development.com/midi-tutorial.html) it seems the Reset message should be used cautiously:

> - MIDI Reset message
>
>   - This is a one status byte message 0xFF, without data bytes. It should reset the synthesizer to its power-on default, so it also stops
>     all notes playing. Use this message sparingly, as it reset the full
>     synthesizer, not only the notes playing.

I would suggest:

- Sending only *one* reset message
- Adding a delay after sending it. You will have to test an appropriate value